# Is there a way to change number format in Google Sheets based on formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, spreadsheet, number-formatting

In a Google spreadsheet, I am using an array formula to insert data from another sheet. The header (top row) is the date which the data corresponds. When annual is selected, the date is in *yyyy* format, while quarterly displays *mm/dd/yyyy*. My problem is, if I change it to regular number format, quarterly data is displayed as a 6 digit number that only the computer can interpret, but using the data format makes the annual dates another date. How can I fix this without having to change format every time I switch between quarterly and annual?

[image: My spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

Without your actual spreadsheet or array formula, it is hard to give an exact answer, but my best suggestion would be to use an IF statement combined with TEXT functions.

Here is an example of what I mean -

[image: ex]

[image: ex2]

`=arrayformula(if(A2="Quarterly", text(B2:D2, "mm/dd/yyyy"), text(B2:D2, "yyyy")))`

You can use this concept and incorporate it into your existing array function in order to return your desired result.

Please let me know if you have any questions, or would like me to explain anything. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this. Sorry since I am restricted on what I can post pictures about. I will see if I can provide more context

Comment: @NickW It's no problelm, even if you were just able to provide the array formula you are using, I could provide an adapted formula

Comment: I just made some adjustments and I imported the data and dates separately. This was necessary since the data was being imported by using vlookup for the date from the database. I think it is resolved now. Thanks again

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 Please do NOT use just images. Do write the proposed formulas as well. Images are not searchable. Please read [answer].

Comment: @marikamitsos My bad! I fully meant to include the formula but it slipped my mind before posting, thanks for the reminder. My answer has been updated.